# How to define onClickListener on programmatically created Button in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view in which I create new buttons on programmatically depending on the array size for that particular position.

That said, I need to implement onClickListener to those Buttons, I DID but inside the adapter and I need to do it from the main activity...  is it possible and how??

thanks in advance.

Main activity

```
private void setAdapter()
{

    ComandaAdapter adapter =  new ComandaAdapter(this , lista_Comanda, seteador);

    //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(-1,lista_Comanda.size());//va en 0 supeustamente -1 es default
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(lista_Comanda.size()); //ver si hay que cambiar con cada item
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int position;

            if (view.getId() == R.id.)
            {


                position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition((View) view.getParent());

                mostrarMensaje(position + "");


            }
          /*  else
            {

            }*/

        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

as you can see i cant find the button the Adapter's OnClickListener becasuse it is not defined in the layout.. it is a programmaticallya added button here is my Row you will see the section where I do Add controls pragrammatically

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/elpadre"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--   Recycler View Item Row   -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/comanda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyocabeza"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_comanda"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size"
            android:text="Comanda:"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_comanda"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lbl_comanda"
            android:hint="00000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_mesa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size"
            android:hint="9999"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_mesa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size"
            android:text="Mesa:"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_mesa"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cerrar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lbl_comanda"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/ctexto"
            android:text="Cerrar Comanda"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/torden"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lyocabeza">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyocomanda"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/lyocabeza">

            <!--   HERE THE PROGRAMMATICALLY ADDED STUFF   -->



        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my adapter

```
public class ComandaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComandaAdapter.ComandaAdapterViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener{

private Boolean funcion;//controla el funcionamiento de la comanda
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<DataRoot> list_comandas;
private Seteadores seteador;

private View.OnClickListener listener;


public ComandaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataRoot> list_comandas, Seteadores seteador)
{
    this.mContext = context;
    this.list_comandas = list_comandas;
    this.seteador = seteador;
}

@Override
public ComandaAdapter.ComandaAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    funcion = true;
    if (seteador.getSwfuncion() != null)
    {
        funcion = seteador.getSwfuncion();
    }



    return new ComandaAdapter.ComandaAdapterViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ComandaAdapter.ComandaAdapterViewHolder holder, final int position)
{

    final DataRoot dataRoot = list_comandas.get(position);


    holder.setData(dataRoot);


    for (final Button button : holder.Articulos)
    {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                button.setEnabled(false);
                holder.loadRetrofitComandaid(dataRoot.get_id(), button, false);

                    holder.Bhabilitado.remove(button);
                    if (holder.Bhabilitado.size() == 0)
                    {
                        holder.habilitador = true;
                    }

                holder.btn_cerrar.setEnabled(holder.habilitador);
                if (holder.btn_cerrar.isEnabled()){holder.btn_cerrar.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getColorStateList(R.color.ccomanda));}

            }
        });
    }


    holder.btn_cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (funcion)
            {
                removeItem(holder.getLayoutPosition());
            }
            else
            {
                holder.btn_cerrar.setEnabled(false);
                holder.btn_cerrar.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getColorStateList(R.color.cboff));

                //ACA ENVIAR EL CAMBIO DE STATUS DE LA ORDEN


            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{

    return list_comandas.size();

}

private void removeItem(int position)
{
    list_comandas.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}


public void mostrarMensaje(String mensaje)
{
    Toast.makeText(mContext, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void updateRetrofitEstadoitem(int position, String id, String catego)
{
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.20:3000/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    IRequestestadoitem request = retrofit.create(IRequestestadoitem.class);

    Estadoitem estadoitem = new Estadoitem();
    estadoitem.setEstadoitem("listo");
    estadoitem.setPosition(position);
    estadoitem.setCategoria(catego);// aca la categoria

    Call<Estadoitem> call = request.updateEstadoitem(id, estadoitem);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Estadoitem>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Estadoitem> call, Response<Estadoitem> response) {

            Log.i("UPDATE ESTADO", "Termino PUT");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Estadoitem> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error " , t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (listener != null)
    {
        listener.onClick(view);
    }
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener)
{
    this.listener = listener;
}
public class ComandaAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    //definicioin de variables

    ArrayList<Button> Articulos;
    ArrayList<Button> Bhabilitado;

    ArrayList<Entradas> entrada;
    ArrayList<String> contornogen;
    ArrayList<Fondos> fondo;
    ArrayList<Postres> postre;


    TimeZone tz;
    DateFormat df;

    private TextView txt_comanda;
    private TextView txt_mesa;
    private TextView tid;
    private TextView torden;
    private TextView hora;
    private TextView te;

    private Integer tag;
    private Boolean habilitador;

    //private Boolean funcion;//CONTROLA EL COMPROTAMIENTO DE CERRAR COMANDA

   // private Button btn_cerrar;
    private Button be;
    private Button btn_cerrar;



    private LinearLayout le;
    private LinearLayout lyocomanda;
    private LinearLayout elpadre;


    int getScreenWidth() {return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;}

    public ComandaAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //INICIALIZAR CONTROLES

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        tz = cal.getTimeZone();
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        df.setTimeZone(tz);

        elpadre = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.elpadre);

        lyocomanda = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyocomanda);

        txt_comanda = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_comanda);

        txt_mesa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_mesa);

        tid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tid);

        torden = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.torden);

        btn_cerrar = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_cerrar);

        Articulos = new ArrayList<>();

        Bhabilitado = new ArrayList<>();

        habilitador=false;

    }

    void setData(DataRoot dataRoot) {

        Integer id = -1;
        String comandero;/////////////////////////////ACA VARIABLES DE SETEO DE DATA



      /*CONFIGURTACIONES INICIALES DE CADA VIEW*/

        if (getAdapterPosition()<10)
        {
            comandero = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            comandero="";
        }

        txt_comanda.setText(comandero + getAdapterPosition()+ "");

        txt_mesa.setText(dataRoot.getMesa());

        tid.setText(dataRoot.get_id());     //para el proceso de PUT

        torden.setText(dataRoot.getEstado_orden());//para el proceso de PUT

        int copantalla;
        int dipantalla = getScreenWidth();


        if (dipantalla < 2400){
            copantalla = 2;// smaller device
        }
        else
        {
            copantalla = 4;// 6.5inch device or bigger
        }

        elpadre.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dipantalla/copantalla, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        String date = df.format(dataRoot.getFechaorden());


        entrada = dataRoot.getOrden().getEntradas();
        tag = -1;
        for (Entradas extraer : entrada )
        {
            tag = tag + 1;
            id = id + 1;
            ColorStateList color = mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.entradas, null);
            int idr = Integer.parseInt(txt_comanda.getText().toString() + id);
            creaboton(idr, color, extraer.getEntrada(), date, tag);


            contornogen = extraer.getContornos(getAdapterPosition());
            int valiconto = contornogen.size();

              if (valiconto > 0 )
              {
                  crearcontor();
                  contornogen.clear();
              }
        }

        fondo = dataRoot.getOrden().getFondos();
        tag = -1;
        for (Fondos extraer : fondo)
        {
            tag = tag + 1;
            id = id + 1;
            ColorStateList color = mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.fondos, null);
            int idr = Integer.parseInt(txt_comanda.getText().toString() + id);
            creaboton(idr, color, extraer.getFondo(), date,tag);


            contornogen = extraer.getContornos(getAdapterPosition());
            int valiconto = contornogen.size();

            if (valiconto > 0 )
            {
                crearcontor();
                contornogen.clear();
            }
        }

        postre = dataRoot.getOrden().getPostres();
        tag = -1;
        for (Postres extraer : postre)
        {
            tag = tag + 1;
            id = id + 1;
            ColorStateList color = mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.postres, null);
            int idr = Integer.parseInt(txt_comanda.getText().toString() + id);
            creaboton(idr, color, extraer.getPostre(), date, tag);


            contornogen = extraer.getContornos(getAdapterPosition());
            int valiconto = contornogen.size();

            if (valiconto > 0 )
            {
                crearcontor();
                contornogen.clear();
            }
        }

    }

    void creaboton (Integer idr, ColorStateList color, String extraer, String date, Integer tag)
    {
        be = new Button(mContext);


        be.setId(idr);
        be.setTag(tag);//TAG INDICA LA POSICION DE RESETEO EN EL ARRAY DE LA BASE DE DATOS
        be.setPadding(15,15,15,15);
        be.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        be.setBackgroundTintList(color);
        be.setTextColor(mContext.getColorStateList(R.color.ctexto));
        be.setText(extraer);
        be.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        hora = new TextView(mContext);
        hora.setText(extraer + ": " + date);
        hora.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        lyocomanda.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        String id = tid.getText().toString();

        loadRetrofitComandaid(id, be, true);//verificar el status en la base de datos del boton


        lyocomanda.addView(be);
        lyocomanda.addView(hora);
        Articulos.add(be);
        Bhabilitado.add(be);


    }

    void crearcontor()
    {

        Boolean creador = true;

        for (String contorno : contornogen)
        {
            te = new TextView(mContext);
            te.setText(contorno);
            te.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            if (creador){
                le = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                creador = false;
            }

            le.addView(te);

        }

        le.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        le.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        le.setBackground(mContext.getDrawable(customborder));
        lyocomanda.addView(le);

    }
```

and here is the label in the main activity row I need to change when i press the programmatically generated buttons

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_nminute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="N Plato por Minuto"
        android:textSize="80dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/reloj_media"/>
```

in the adapter the programmatically button is called "be"

here is an image of how my app looks, when i press the colored buttons on the recycler that are generated programmatically, the Textview on the picture placed in the main activity (same astivity as the recyclerview) needs to change

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just pass a reference to your Activity in the adapter and inside the onClick calling

```
 myActivity.onClick(int position)
```

that you can define in the Activity?

Comment: and what i f i have a textview in my main activity and i want to change its value every time i press a button in the recycler, how do i inflate that view to the recycler, what would be the best practice here

Comment: If you want to change something in another class you should probably just use an iterface

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite easy:

You've got the possibility to check a view and an index value.

First you have to check if youre button was pressed

```
 if(view.getId() == R.id.your_button_id)
```

after you've done that you can look up in which item of your recyclerview the button was pressed by using

```
getAdapterPosition();
```

To sum it up: If you want to push out a toast when the button in the second item was clicked

```
if(view.getId() == R.id.your_button && getAdapterPosition() == 1)
```

**UPDATE**

 As I said, it is acutally quite easy. To change the TextView in the MainActivity I'd recommend you to use an interface. I also think it would be better to set the OnClickListener inside your adapter.

First implement `View.OnClickListener` inside your ViewHolder in the Adapter
then generate the overriden Method `onClick(View view)`.

Build an interface like this one

```
public interface RecyclerViewOnClickListener {
   void onItemClicked(View view, int position);
}
```

and implement it inside your MainActivity and also generate the overriden function.
Pass this interface to your ViewAdapter constructor and place it inside a variable.

Now you can access it in your onClick function in your ViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        mRecyclerInterface.onItemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition());
}
```

Inside your MainActivity you can now go into your onItemClicked function and check for the index value and the tag of your button.

```
@Override
public void onItemClicked(View view, int position){
     if(view.getTag() == "sampleTag" && position == 1){
         //DO STUFF WITH YOUR LABEL
     }
}
```

Comment: if(view.getId() == R.id.your_button_id) i can do this by implementing onClickListener to the adapter, thats no problem, the hard part is this part  `R.id.your_button` the button is not declared anywhere it is generated programmatically, it has a proper tag and proper id but i CANT know what they are until generated

Comment: you just need to use the id, you gave it in your layout file your inflating in your adapter

Comment: they do not exist in the layout they are created as needed

Comment: You can just set a tag, and combine it with getting the adapter position

Comment: oh I was thinking about it, gonna try and comment back

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, you and Lorenzo helped a lot to solve my issue, what bothers me is the down votes, seems like of you don't know the answer or dont understand a question, instead of leaving they gotta down vote? That I dont like from this site

Comment: At the point you asked the question it was quite hard to get what you actually wanted to ask. Now its pretty clear